# Additional information added to a delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, observablecollection

Perhaps this question has been asked and solved many times, but I may be using the wrong terms, for I've not come up with an answer thus far.

So I have an ObservableCollection and I've used reflection to call the 'CollectionChanged' event handler.

It looks like this ('o' being the ObservableCollection in question, also obtained by reflection):

```
                EventInfo evi = o.GetType().GetEvent("CollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var eventHandler = new Action<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                    (s, a) => 
                    {
                        // Event code here
                    });

                 var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evi.EventHandlerType, eventHandler.Method);

                 evi.AddEventHandler(o, del);
```

The calling of this action is automated and is called on a change to the elements of the property 'o'. I can call message boxes and such like, but I wish to capture some kind of information inside this action. In particular, the class in which this all sits has an ID which is a simple int. I would like to capture this int and use it within the action. I can't seem to add any additional parameters due to the automated nature of it, so I'm not sure how to manage that.

**Edit:**

I thought what I'd do is create a new project and try to isolate the problem I had. Just to be clear on where this ended up, I tried simply referencing a property within the event that existed in the class which the event was declared in and I got the 'cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type' exception. Would I still see the problem? That's what I wanted to find out.

The code is here: [Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EZ1t8Y)

It's pretty simple and is just a test class. All the rest of the code does (MainWindow.xaml.cs since it's a WPF project), is create an instance of TestClass, sets TestInt to 10001, and then calls TestMethod on that instance.

Without the 'this.TestInt' in the event, it works fine. With it, the exception is still there.

Comment: You can not use an additional parameter, that would create another method signature and the delegates would be incompatible. Instead you can just use the code you have and when you access somethings that is outside your lambda it will be captured for you without a change in the method signature.
So `Console.WriteLine(this.MyIntegerField)` inside your lambda should just work.

Comment: Thank you once more for your help, however I had tried that in the first instance, but if I add the line 'int x = this.ID', it not longer works. The line 'var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evi.EventHandlerType, eventHandler.Method);' throws an exception with this message: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Comment: Please provide the full code to reproduce your problem inside your question. One version that works and another that does not would be good.

Comment: Okay, done! Please see the edit.

Comment: Ok I see, as soon as the lambda captures something the compiler introduces an invisble `this` parameter because now the lambda needs a state. I will write up a little answer in a moment. Anyway I recommend you to give sharplab.io a try and see how your code looks after compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the lambda capture results in the creation of a state object, you have to consider the `Target` when creating a new delegate from the old one. So you need to use the following `CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo)` overload. This method is safe even for delegates without a target object, the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) tells us about the object parameter:

> The object to which the delegate is bound, or null to treat method as static (Shared in Visual Basic).

The following adaption of your code should do the job:

```
var o = p.GetValue(this,null);
EventInfo eventInfo = t.GetEvent("CollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var handler = new Action<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>((s, a) => { Console.WriteLine("Changed + " + this.TestInt.ToString()); });

Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, handler.Method);

eventInfo.AddEventHandler(o, del);
```